# Error comsuming WCF service metadata?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, biztalk

We have a WCF webservice selfhosted in a windows service application.

It works fine to generate and call a simple method from both a .NET winform application and SoapUI(after changin to correct IP and set authentication header).

**The problem** is that when trying to add the WSDL to a BizTalk we get *"Error consuming WCF service metadata. Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*. and nothing more.

I have search internet and there is some that have hade the same problem and they are talking about namespace problems. I have checked the generated .NET winform proxy but there is no warnings or anything that might suggest problems with namespaces? I notice in the WSDL that some namespaces tags do only have a "" value but not sure if that might be a problem.

Is there any way to get more information from Biztalk about where the error might be in this massive WSDL?

When browsing the WSDL from another computer it will use localhost(instead of the IP och DNS) so I have to use WSDL singelfile to genereate the proxy and I have to manually change the URL to the specific IP in the client to get it working. This should however not be the problem.

Here is how the service is started :

```
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(T), new Uri(baseEndpoint.Address));
    ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttleBehavior = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
                {
                    MaxConcurrentCalls = 200,
                    MaxConcurrentInstances = 2147483647,
                    MaxConcurrentSessions = 2000,
                };
    _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttleBehavior);
    _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb.HttpGetEnabled = true);
    foreach (var endpointDescription in _additionalServiceEndpoints)
                {
                    var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription, endpointDescription.Binding, new EndpointAddress(endpointDescription.Address));
                    _endpointBehaviors.ForEach(c => endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(c));
                    _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);
                }
    _serviceBehaviors.ForEach(c => _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(c));

    ServiceAuthorizationBehavior serviceAuthorizationBehavior = _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceAuthorizationBehavior>();
                if (serviceAuthorizationBehavior == null)
                {
                    _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceAuthorizationBehavior());
                }
                if (_authorizationPolicies.Count > 0)
                {
                    serviceAuthorizationBehavior.ExternalAuthorizationPolicies = new ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy>(_authorizationPolicies.ToArray());
                    serviceAuthorizationBehavior.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.Custom;
                    serviceAuthorizationBehavior.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new CustomServiceAuthorizationManager();
                }
                ((ServiceBehaviorAttribute)_serviceHost.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceBehaviorAttribute)]).MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;
                ((ServiceBehaviorAttribute)_serviceHost.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceBehaviorAttribute)]).IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

    _serviceHost.Open();
```

Comment: How specifically do you add the WSDL to BizTalk? Do you use Visual Studio? Have you tried using a tool like WSDL Analyzer to validate your WSDL? https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/

Comment: Im not sure how the WSDL is used within BizTalk but I know that it worked fine a couple of versions(of my webservice) ago. The changes is to great to just compare(old and new) and find problems in the WSDL.

WSDL Analyzer sounds good but my webservice is not accessible from internet so I will have to finde a offline WSDL Analyzer.

Comment: You say in your question you add the WSDL to BizTalk and get the error. How do you do that specifically? Also, you can download the WSDL from your web service (append ?wsdl to your URL) and upload it to such a service.

Comment: I have no tested the WSDL here www.wsdl-analyzer.com and the only warning is about element naming inconsitensy, 1 upper camel case and 20 lower camel case. This should not be a problem with BizTalk I hope. I will check how the WSDL is added to BizTalk.

Comment: I have now checked and the WSDL is added to the Biztalk from within Visual Studio : VS > Right click project(BizTalk)>Add Genereated Item. Choose consume WCF service > Mex endpoint and supply the singel WSDL URL. The Biztalk WCF Service Consuming Wizard will throw a Completing the BizTalk WCF Service consuming: Error consuming WCF service metadata. Object reference not set to an instance fthe object.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the solution which is described in this forum thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19105b96-5ec4-40f1-972b-2e04f889061f/biztalk-2010-error-consuming-wcf-service-metadata-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an?forum=biztalkgeneral

It points to a blog post located here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kerreybpi/2009/02/05/biztalk-error-wcf-service-consuming-wizard/

The solution might be (from the link above):

1, Generate WSDL and XSD files by using svcutil tool

> svcutil.exe /t:metadata http://yourservice

2, Verify  nodes in WSDL file, make sure the node has a target namespace define. It doesn't matter what attribute value you use, maybe just looks like http://any.

3, Select Metadata Files(WSDL and XSD) as the source

4, Everything should be fine.

Comment: This have already been tested by the user but I will take a closer look. Generate and modifie the WSDL, then let the user use it with there Biztalk.

Comment: I have exported the WSDL with Svcutil, I get 11 file. When checking the Myservice WSDL file I can see that the XSD:schema have a targetNameSpace. After this I got a couple of import and one of these have no namespace set. I dont know what namespace I should set here? If I visit the import I can see that the xs:schema do not have any targetnamespace or namespace? could this be the problem? It does have a import to ?xsd=xsd0 and this got a namespace.

Comment: Some of the Namespaces that is set looks like this : "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "MyApp.ServiceImplementation" and http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Orbit.DataContracts.External

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error when trying to consume .svc?singleWsdl. When I consume as just .svc into the "Add Generated Items" wizard then it works.